# Error on string '\0' null while concatenating

Tags: c++, string, null

So I am trying to concatenate simple strings, and make a final sentence.

```
int main()
{
    string I ("I");
    string Love ("Love");
    string STL ("STL,");
    string Str ("String.");
    string fullSentence = '\0';

    // Concatenate
    fullSentence = I + " " + Love + " " + STL + " " + Str;
    cout << fullSentence;

    return 0;
}
```

Here, I didn't want to have "fullSentence" with nothing, so I assigned null and it gives me an error. There is no certain error message, except the following which I do not understand at all... :

Exception thrown at 0x51C3F6E0 (ucrtbased.dll) in exercise_4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000. occurred

Soon as I remove '\0', it works just fine. Why does it so?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to accomplish with `string fullSentence = '\0';`. If you want an empty string, just use `string fullSentence;`.

Comment: @interjay yes that is what I did but I was wondering the reason of why '\0' is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `"\0"` instead of `'\0'`. In C++ `''` is for char and `""` is for strings.

It's a conversion from `char` to non-scalar type `std::string`

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be an MSVC compiler bug to me.

The statement:

```
string fullSentence = '\0';
```

is not supposed to compile.

---

Indeed, there is no valid (implicit) constructor from `char` (i.e. `'\0'`) to `std::string`. [Reference Here](http://eel.is/c%2B%2Bdraft/string.cons).

---

Note that [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/-IybW9) and [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/zYFJ9I) do not accept this code as valid.
[MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/IMTgdf) does.

---

> Why does it so?

Looking at the assembly code, MSVC compiles that statement with the following constructor:

```
std::string::string(char const * const);
```

Passing `'\0'` as an argument, it will be converted into a `nullptr` actually.

So:

> Constructs the string with the contents initialized with a copy of the null-terminated character string pointed to by s. The length of the string is determined by the first null character. The behavior is undefined if [s, s + Traits::length(s)) is not a valid range (**for example, if s is a null pointer**).

So your code is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for such details. I understand much better now!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a debugger to see a call stack of what happened. 
Looking into string class [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) 
Below constructor was called in your case:

```
basic_string( const CharT* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

> As per description of the constructor (emphasis mine) Constructs the
>   string with the contents initialized with a **copy of the
>   null-terminated character string** pointed to by s. The length of the
>   string is determined by the first null character. **The behavior is
>   undefined if [s, s + Traits::length(s)) is not a valid range**

in your case range is empty -> invalid.